# changing class on DIV before knockout removes it from DOM works 95% of the time

Tags: knockout.js

What approach would have to be taken to prevent a change of class on a DIV, immediately prior to its removal from the DOM, from causing the removal to fail? I am mixing jQuery and knockout, and maybe there's a "purer" way of doing this in knockout that would work 100% of the time?

```
              self.DeleteDIV = function (el$) {
                el$.removeClass("foo").addClass("deleted");
                setTimeout(function() {                        
                     self.myObservableArray.splice(el$.index(), 1);
                    }
                },222);
            }
```

The class `foo` has set the background image. This class is removed. The `.deleted` class adds a different image (e.g. recycle icon) to the to-be-deleted div, and after some delay, the item is removed from the observable array that created the div in the first place, via `foreach` binding.

I've been playing with the timeout delay, but a small percentage of the time, the recycle icon stays on screen and the DIV does not get removed from the DOM.

P.S. The DeleteDIV is triggered by a click on the div-to-be-deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand what you are trying to do - are you just trying to remove a div from a list?

If so create a function on your view model that takes in a clicked div or something and removes it -

```
self.DeleteDIV = function (el$) {
    el$.removeClass("foo").addClass("deleted");
    setTimeout(function() {                        
         self.myObservableArray.remove(el$);
        }
    },222);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to display, very briefly, a visual indication that the clicked-on div will be removed from the DOM, and then remove the DIV from the DOM, which should cause its contents to disappear from the page.

Comment: The "visual indicator" that I hope to use is a change of background image.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use `$.switchClass` of jqueryUI with a delete css with some animation to get the effect. here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhanasekaran/e7ec3/1/)

```
self.removeItem=function(item,event){
    $(event.target).switchClass('icon-male','icon-male icon-spin',1000,'swing',function(){
        self.items.remove(item);
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later today when I am back at my desk.  That it can run a callback function when the animation is completed looks like it should do the trick. Although it does say `Not all styles can be animated. For example, there is no way to animate a background image. Any styles that cannot be animated will be changed at the end of the animation.`  I hope that means that the completed callback fires after the style-change, and that I'm not still in the same predicament.